# laravel 5 showing directory structure in vps

Tags: laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5 in my vps form the instruction given in the "http://laravel.com/docs/5.1" link. It installed successfully but when I go to http://myipaddress/laravel it showing me the directory structure. I had check my php.ini file also for the "mod_rewrite" and it is showing in the loaded package, so where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Access the `public` folder. That's where all your output content goes. http://myipaddress/laraval/public/

### Edit:

One other thing. Don't name your project "laravel" as it may cause naming problems. Try to create a new project with a different name.

Comment: I had check this page but it's showing a blank page

Comment: let me remove this and install it with new name. thanks for your help

Comment: I have installed it with the new folder name and its working in the public folder " http://myipaddress/tmb/public/". but do i need to work with this public folder? or this can be removed

Comment: @Susain that will depend on your goal. For RESTful APIs, you won't be working with views output at all. For MVC application, you'll be working with the `resources` folder, which allows you to create views through Blade Framework. I recommend you to check out http://laracasts.com. One reminder is that to access the output, you use the public folder, but to "develop" your application, you probably won't be touching the public folder.

Comment: I am developing the MVC application. I had check the tutorial for given in the "laracast" and I have installed the application with the composer also but all gives me the working link with the public folder. How to remove that public form url and why it is coming in the link, I have also run this process in my xampp and same happening

Comment: It's suppose to work within the `public` folder. When deploying your application into a server, you'll be given a `public` folder aswell. That's where you'll deploy your application and you'll be able to keep the files that are not public outside of the public folder and prevent them from being served by the host. In Xampp, it's the equivalent to the `httpdocs`, if I'm not mistaken.